# PHP socket_select() returns blocking socket

Tags: php, sockets, select

I just started to learn socket programming in php. I implemented socket_select for handling multiple connections. But the function also returns sockets that has no data to read which results in a blocking socket_read function. Code below:

```
function main() {

  global $__sockets;

  $ssock = createServerSocket("192.168.0.11","8080");
  $__sockets[] = $ssock;

  $write = array();
  $except = array();

  $run = 1;
  while ($run) {
    usleep(100000);

    $read_sockets = $__sockets;

    echo "Waiting for action...\n";
    $select = socket_select($read_sockets, $write, $except, NULL);
    if ( $select === false) {
        echo "socket_select() failed, Reason: " .
    socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
    }

    echo "Number of changes from socket_select(): $select\n";
    echo "Number of sockets in read_sockets: ".count($read_sockets)."\n";
    foreach ($read_sockets as $socket) {
        echo "Action detected in Socket: ".$socket."\n";
    }

    if (in_array($ssock, $read_sockets)) {

        $__sockets[] = $newsock = @socket_accept($ssock);

        socket_getpeername($newsock, $ip);
        echo "New connection from: $ip. ID: ".$newsock."\n";
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($read_sockets as $read) {
        echo "Reading...$read\n";
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read ($read, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() failed. Reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($read)) . "\n";
            break;
        }

        echo $buf."\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Waiting for action...
Number of changes from socket_select(): 1
Number of sockets in read_sockets: 1
Action detected in Socket: Resource id #4
New connection from: 192.168.0.24. ID: Resource id #5
Waiting for action...
Number of changes from socket_select(): 1
Number of sockets in read_sockets: 1
Action detected in Socket: Resource id #5
Reading...Resource id #5
```

The Client just connects using Putty Telnet. No User Inputs. Socket_select indicates changes on this socket, but socket_read blocks and does not get any data. Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?